# Are there any free command line based zip utility?

Tags: windows, command-line, zip

I need to schedule a command line to zip contents of a couple of folders. Are there any free command line based utility that can handle multi volumes?

(7Zip is disqualified, the -v parameter is not implemented yet)

EDIT: 7Zip does indeed work with the -v parameter if used as described in the help file, and not according to the .exe's help output.

EDIT2: On closer inspection, there is something strange going on, and here's the reason I got the "Not implemented" error message:
(On a Windows 2008 Server x64 with U.S. locale):

```
@ECHO OFF
SET MYFILENAME=Backup-IIs-%date:~-4,4%-%date:~-10,2%-%date:~-7,2%.7z
ECHO %MYFILENAME%
"c:\program files\7-zip\7z" a "c:\backup\%MYFILENAME%" c:\inetpub\*.* -r -v49m
```

Result: System Error: Not implemented.

Changing it to (notice dot instead of dash in filename):

```
@ECHO OFF
SET MYFILENAME=Backup.IIs-%date:~-4,4%-%date:~-10,2%-%date:~-7,2%.7z
ECHO %MYFILENAME%
"c:\program files\7-zip\7z" a "c:\backup\%MYFILENAME%" c:\inetpub\*.* -r -v49m
```

And 7Zip is happy....
Can someone explain?

Comment: please describe your expectations from the '`-v`' parameter or link to details elsewhere.

Comment: way back when, I used pkzip and pkunzip...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the record, '`-v`' option in [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org) command line is used for [creating](http://www.bugaco.com/7zip/MANUAL/switches/volume.htm) [volumes](http://sevenzip.sourceforge.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/volume.htm).
Here is a short description on [Creating Multi-volume Archives with 7-zip](http://www.hacksawlabs.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=64:creating-multi-volume-archives-with-7-zip&catid=36:system-administration&Itemid=53).

Can you please explain what you mean by
"*7Zip is disqualified, the -v parameter is not implemented yet*"?

Comment: Hmmm. it seems that it was the order of the command switches that confused 7zip. The .exe reports that it wants <commands> <switches> <archive_name>. But that doesn't work, It gives "not implemented". It should be <commands> <archive_name> <switches>

Answer (score 5):

Most of the GNU command-line utilities are ported to windows, including zip:

http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/zip.htm

For multi-volumes you must post-process the archive with zipsplit (included in same package).

Comment: Just for the record: The zip utility in gnuwin32 is from Info-ZIP, not from GNU.

Answer (score 2):

Well for linux you can tar and gz zip folders via command line, but i'm going to assume your on windows?

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe the output of any compressor that supports writing to `stdout`, such as `tar` with either its `gzip` or `bzip2` options, through the relatively standard `split` command. This will compress and split the result without having an intermediate (unsplit) archive file

You can unpack the result by `cat`ing the files together and piping that through to the decompresser.

This will output all the files in one go (or use all the files in one go for the decompression step) - so if you are looking for something that supports prompting you to put in the next floppy/cd/dvd/... disk in at each step this is no good to you.

There are many ports of these utilities available for Windows environments.

Comment: for pedanticy - `tar` doesn't compress, it's an archiver; whereas `bzip2` and `gzip` are the compression tools :)  ..also - `bzip2` almost always gets better compression, but tends to be *much* slower than `gzip` in my experience

Comment: For extra pedanticy bzip2 performs transformation then compression rather than just compression (the BW transform [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burrows-Wheeler_transform] is both why it gets better compression rates than gzip and why it takes much longer to do so). You can make the tar==archive gzip/bzip2==compress distinction obvious by using an explicit pipe to/from gzip/bzip2 on the command line instead of tar's -z/-j options. Many incorrectly assume tar does the compression itself because with -z/-j they don't see the separate command (unless they check in ps/pstree while it is running).

Answer (score 1):

[Zipgenius](http://www.zipgenius.com/) allows command line options. So you can extract and compress archives from command line.

Answer (score 0):

After spending some time with the problem myself it turns out that having a .7z as part of your archive name will be the problem.

When creating volumes 7Zip will name them .001, .002, etc. and already naming your archive as .7z seems to cause it a bit of a headache.

It's a very poor error message, but a simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

After windows 10 Creators update (build 1803) comes with some linux tools, one of them is `tar` which you can easily use in your batch files.

Comment: tar doesn't support zip archives